# i want to share video to whatsapp thta video is playing inside my app in video_player activity

Tags: android

I have video links inside my app and by clicking on video  that video is start playing inside my app in video_player activity on clicking of share button i want to share that video to WhatsApp or other social apps

```
    url = getIntent().getStringExtra("live_video_url");
            Log.e("url" , "-->"+url);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent ( );
    shareIntent.setAction ( Intent.ACTION_SEND ); // temp permission for receiving app to read this file
    shareIntent.setType ( "text/plain" );
    shareIntent.setFlags ( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
    shareIntent.putExtra ( Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://com.careerguide"+url );
    startActivity ( Intent.createChooser ( shareIntent, "Choose an app" ) );
```

Comment: You are not actually sharing a video . You are just sharing link of video .. Also you whats the problem with this code ?

Comment: i want to share link of video with my app link. When the user clicks on link first it is checked whether the user has app installed in his device or not. If the app is installed video should be played automatically otherwise option to download app must be viewed to the user.

Comment: can uh please tell me

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your question that you've video link and you want to share it to Whatsapp through your Application.
If that's correct then try this code:

```
url = getIntent().getStringExtra("live_video_url"); //get URL of your video
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("text/plain");
share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT , "https://com.careerguide"+url); // Your link here
try {
    startActivity(share);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(this , "Whatsapp isn't installed on your device!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I hope it will work with you.

Comment: i want to share link of video with my app link. When the user clicks on link first it is checked whether the user has app installed in his device or not. If the app is installed video should be played automatically otherwise option to download app must be viewed to the user.